# Converting Likert Scales

Tags: data-transformation

We collected data on a 7-point survey and it should have been on a 9-point scale. How do you convert a 7-point scale to a 9-point scale?

Comment: I would say that the general answer is "you don't". 

But why do you say it "should" have been collected on a 9 point scale? Are you are trying to compare it to other data that was collected using a 9 point scale? Or are you attempting to merge it with other data? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You should not convert individual answers.

---

However, if you want to compare your work in the 7 point scale with a different work on a 9 point scale, you can make a linear transform of the type:
$$
y = \frac{x-m}{a}
$$
where $x$ is the mean or the median in the 7 point scale, $m$ is the minimum of that scale, $m=1$ in your case, and $a$ is the amplitude of the scale, in that case it will be $a = 7 - 1 = 6$.
For the 9 point scale, the transformation formula is the same, but $a = 9 - 1 = 8$.
Note that the standard deviation and the variance will each have their own transformations.

The transformed value will be in the interval $[0; 1]$ and you may find that, for instance, $4.2$ in the 7 point scale corresponds to a higher value than $4.8$ in the 9 point scale.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to comment on the original post. I will delete my comment on your answer

Comment: OK. No worries.